# Error generating random float number in Swift

Tags: swift

I get an error when trying to run my project, the error is as follows.

Type CGFLoat has no member "random"

```
var randomPosition = CGFloat.random (min: -200, max: 200)
wallPair.position.y = wallPair.position.y +  randomPosition
wallPair.addChild(scoreNode)
```

Comment: What makes you think that `CGFloat` has a `random(min:,max:)` method?

Answer (score 0):

You must create another swift file to make it use .random

```
import Foundation
import CoreGraphics

public extension CGFloat{

    public static func random() -> CGFloat{
        return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)
    }

    public static func random(min min : CGFloat, max : CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
        return CGFloat.random() * (max - min) + min
    }    
}
```